# $localize with conditional statement in Angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next

I'm using **i18n** for Internalization in my Angular app.

For HTML, I am using `i18n="@@<unique_Id>"` and for dynamic elements which are defined in TS class files I am using `$localize`

```
Example: this.buttontext = $localize`:@@Security.Ok:Click to Continue`;
```

I want to know how to use it for conditional statements as shown below:

```
this.questionLabel = this.screenType == 'reset' ? 'Question' : 'Question 1';
```

And also for dynamic strings as shown below:

```
this.dialogTitle = `Select Rollback point - ${this.data.number}`
```

Comment: Is this an Angular or AngularJS question?

Comment: @Bargros it's Angular

Answer (score 0):

To use localization from code Angular (since version 11) supports tagged templates in form of

```
$localize`Text to translate`
```

Since $localize is a just function call so in case of condition you can use it like that:

```
this.questionLabel = this.screenType == 'reset' ? $localize'Question' : $localize'Question 1';
```

And for dynamic string you use the same approach

```
this.dialogTitle = $localize `Select Rollback point - ${this.data.number}`
```

After localization extraction PH placeholder will be generated for your variable ${this.data.number} so you can use it inside your translation

You can read more information form [official blogpost](https://blog.angular.io/angular-localization-with-ivy-4d8becefb6aa)